# how to send a SMS to the emulator from a sender that is a string

Tags: android, android-emulator, sms

I often recieve SMS in my phone that have some string instead of a number in the sender, for example a company name. I would like to test some app that reacts to those SMS, but how can I send such a SMS to the emulator? If I run the emulator and do the following:

telnet localhost 5554 
sms send MyBank this is a test sms

I get an error saying the number is invalid.

Is there a way to test this in the emulator?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the SDK tools. In the emulator control tab on the debug perspective(assuming you are using eclipse) you can push a SMS to your phone.

[image: Picture is worth 1K words]

Comment: that does not work either, it is disabled if the 'Incoming number' is a string a not a number...