# How to start/stop custom built application on remote Android device

Tags: android, eclipse, service, sms, system

I have written an app in Eclipse and now I just need to add an additional method, but I'm wondering how to do it.

Method should listen to incomming messages somehow, and when SMS arrive to device it should start/stop my current app running in background.

So, I send SMS to device with specific content in message (e.g `START123`) and when device receives it, content application will automatically start and perform all further tasks on it.

Any idea/coding on how to accomplish this is welcome.  :)
Thanks and regards.

Comment: You'll need to start by creating a receiver that listens for ``android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED`` broadcasts.

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8720582 do your work from a service.

Don't forget to catch on boot if your app should run after reboots.