# Android : Is it possible to use my data after closing my application

Tags: android

I have stored some phone number in my application.

I want to do some operation like when i get message from that stored number then I want to send the automatic reply.

Once if we close our application then whether the data will be available or not?

After closing application I want to perform this operation with the data which I stored already.

Is it possible?

Comment: Of course, it has been exlained here. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8684772/having-a-service-receive-sms-messages. If you stored in preferences, file, db or something, you can pull from the receiver with no problems :)

Comment: Yes,  you can. Please search content provider in google and in results you can get number of solutions.

Comment: Check : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store small information use **shared preferences,**

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm

**(Or)**

If you want store table of bulk information use **SQLITE database,**

http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/

Comment: @sridhar venkatesan are you got idea?