# sms notification- not working

Tags: android, service, notifications

I'm stuck with something that seems easy. I want to create a simple app that contains of two buttons: one to start a service and a second one to stop it. I've created my `NotifyService` class:

```
public class NotifyService extends Service {
    public NotifyService() {
    }

    private static final String SMS_RECEIVED="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";

    private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            displayNotification(intent);
        }
    };

    private void displayNotification(Intent intent)
    {
       if(intent.getAction().equals(SMS_RECEIVED)) {
           int NOTIFICATION=R.string.local_service_started;

            //notification creating
            Notification.Builder notificationBuilder = new Notification.Builder(this)
                    .setContentText("Otrzymano smsa!")
                    .setContentTitle("SMS!")
                    .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.btn_plus);
            Notification note = notificationBuilder.build();

            //getting system service
            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

            //displaying notification
            notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION, note);
       }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver,new IntentFilter(SMS_RECEIVED));
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
```

And here's the code for my `MainActivity`:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void startServiceBtn(View view)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,NotifyService.class);
        startService(intent);
    }

    public void stopServiceBtn(View view)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,NotifyService.class);
        stopService(intent);
    }
```

And the manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.pablo.myapplication" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name=".NotifyService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true" >
        </service>
    </application>
```

Unfortunately, every time I'm simulating a sending of an sms through `Android Device Monitor`, it doesn't work, it shows me the default system notification (that by the way is shown even without the permission in manifest- ist that right behavior?)

**EDIT:**
In `Android Device Monitor` it still keeps showin `Permission Denial: ... requires android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS due to sender.com android...`. Yet, I've added this into intent filter, then I don't know why it's happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question was related to some other matters with permissions that I had last times and it's connected with new permission politics with Marshmallow. More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32635704/cant-get-the-permission).

So the problem can be solver by switching to lower sdk version or calling appriopriate methods (look into above link) in runtime.